# Passing data from one page to another in razor webpage

Tags: c#, razor

I have a select form which refresh itself after slection 'category' to dispaly 'sub category' I did put validation in subcategory so that user goes to next page only after sub category

I have a code in page 1 like this

```
if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid())
{
    parent = Request.Form["parent"];
    Response.Redirect("~/Members/cb/Page2");
}
```

and in page 2

```
 @Html.Hidden("parent", Request.Form["parent"])
```

however , I cannot get hidden value in page2 that was passed from page 1, pls help

Comment: i am not using mvc, i am doing in web pages

Answer (score 1):

Try pass parent in url to second page:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Members/cb/Page2?parent=" + Request.Form["parent"]);
```

If you do redirect hidden filds will not be available on redirected page. Hidden fields as any other input are only posted back to server on form submit.

Comment: That works, but i have 3 pages to pass and doing this i stuck on how to get first page data in the third ppage

Comment: If you have something like wizard or just need to move it across few page you may just store it to session and use on any page where required.

Comment: I am just wondering if hidden form is better way but not sure why it's not working

Comment: btw i have only 3 pages though

Comment: Hidden field will not work here (at list with approach provided) when you do redirect. Hidden fields are not passed with request on redirect (only on post). If you would like use hidden fields you should do post request to second page (do form submit). You may use cross page post (example here http://forums.asp.net/t/1775220.aspx/1). But it's not likely scenario in asp.net web pages.